# Wordpress have_posts doesn't work in a static page home

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got a problem with the function `have_posts` in my static page home... I would like to have a static page for my home but when I use have_posts in a loop, I don't have any posts but I have pages...

I don't understand what is going wrong...

Have you got an idea to fix that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The have_posts() on a static home page is to show the static home page.

Description
This function checks to see if the current WordPress query has any results to loop over. This is a boolean function, meaning it returns either TRUE or FALSE.

So it checks if the query returns anything (pages,posts,custom content types).

The have_posts() will return TRUE with 1 post(page) in it, the page you set as your static homepage.

Comment: Ok Thanks for this information !

And if I want to have all my posts on my static home page, is it possible ?

Comment: @Kevin86 Then you should not use the static homepage but just set the frontpage display to "Your latest posts". Or Set it to static with a custom page_template which displays all your posts and/or pages.

Comment: Yes, I succeeded with the 2nd option (static with custom page_template).
Thanks for your help !